# PySide2 - adding an event method screws up my view

Tags: events, pyside2

I am trying to create a node graph in pyside2.

It has multiple files, one which handles all the events.
I am implementing the tab keypress event so and just want to print something when tab is pressed. This works fine but when i add the code my whole node graph is cropped and cut off. Seems weird.

Here's the code i add that screws it up:

```
def event(self, event):

    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab: # tab
            event.accept()
            print("Tab pressed")
            return True
```

Before i add the event code:

[image: Before i add the event code]

After I add the event code:

[image: After I add the event code]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Taking your code at face value, you need to append the following line: `return super().event(event)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.